# Fill() method is not throwing an error when it updates a parent property

Tags: c#

I Have a simple Console app that deals a car and an automobile object. The car object has a fill method that updates a property on automobile object. The property on the Automobile object has if statement that checks if the user is putting the correct amount of gas. If the user fills in more gas than what is already in the tank then it should throw an error. This does not happen, when I use the Fill() method to purposely over fill the gas tank no error pops up onto the console. How do I fix this problem?

Car object

```
class Car : AutoMobile
{
    private readonly String _make;
    private readonly int _yearOfManufacturer;
  

    // GasInTank parent property is set to the gasTank the user specifies. the Milage parent property is used in the Drive() method.
    public Car(int gasTank, String color, int milesPerGallon, String make, int yearOfManufacturer) : base(gasTank, color, milesPerGallon)
    {
        _make = make;
        _yearOfManufacturer = yearOfManufacturer;
        GasInTank = gasTank;
        if (_yearOfManufacturer < 1905)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cars didn't exist in this time period.");
        }
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
        GasInTank = GasTank;
    }
    //Fill method takes an integer and is wrapped around a try catch block. If they over fill the gas tank it will thorw an error. 
    public void Fill(int gallonsOfGas)
    {
        try
        {
            GasInTank += gallonsOfGas;
            
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

       
    }


    // takes an integer as a parameter. adds miles to milage property. If GasInTank is zero then it will throw an error
    public void Drive(int miles)
    {
        int milesLeft = miles - GasInTank * MilesPerGallon;
        Milage += miles;
        int gallonsUsed = miles / MilesPerGallon;
        GasInTank = GasInTank - gallonsUsed;
        
        if (GasInTank <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"You have run out of gas!!! You have {milesLeft} miles left to go before you reach your destination.");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Automobile object

```
class AutoMobile : Vehicle
{
    // private readonly int _wheels = 4;
    public readonly int GasTank;
    public readonly String Color;
    public int MilesPerGallon;
    private int _gasInTank;
    public AutoMobile(int gasTank, String color, int milesPerGallon)
    {
        Milage = 0;
        GasInTank = gasTank;
        GasTank = gasTank;
        Color = color;
        MilesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
    }

    public int GasInTank
    {
        get{return _gasInTank;}
        set{
            if(GasInTank >= 0 && GasInTank <= GasTank) {
            _gasInTank = value;
            }
            else {throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("You are over filling the gas tank!");}
        }
         
       
    }

    public int Milage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

Executable file (when I fill the gas tank with 50 gallons nothing happens)

```
class Program
{
    

        try {
            Car myCar = new Car(13, "red", 20, "Mercedes", 1950);
            
            myCar.Fill(50);





        }
        catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
       
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of the scenario where you expect the exception to be thrown? Including constructing the objects with correct values and calling whatever methods should throw the exception

Comment: I use the Fill method fill the gas tank with 50 gallons when the gas tank only holds 13 gallons, this is where an error should be thrown.

Comment: This condition _if(GasInTank >= 0 && GasInTank <= GasTank)_ is always true. You don't check if the added fuel overflows the limit imposed. Also in the constructor for the Car you use the same value _gasTank_ to both set the limit and the content. Is this correct?

Comment: The answer to the second question is yes. I thought else clause would catch it if the user add an integer over the GasTank variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the set part of the GasInTank property.
You must compare `value` instead of `GasInTank`!

```
public int GasInTank
{
    get{return _gasInTank;}
    set{
        if(value >= 0 && value <= GasTank) {
        _gasInTank = value;
        }
        else {throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("You are over filling the gas tank!");}
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an InvalidOperationException, not an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Also check what is the value of GasInTank after this call when you input valid values